# Change Owner from List View for Work Orders

Tags: inline, lightning-quickaction

We are in the Winter 19, I want to be able to 'Change Owner' of Work Orders from a list view.  Logged in User has all permissions.

However, I am not able to add the Quick Action to this Search Layout, as Owner field is not available in the Quick Action layout.  Is this intentional?

Salesforce mentions that row-level action is available.  Also, when I do in-line edit, the owner field is Locked. Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

**when I do in-line edit, the owner field is Locked.**

> Not all fields on records in a list view or multi-line layout view can
>   be edited inline. To find out whether a field supports inline editing,
>   hover over it and look for the pencil Pencil icon. Non-editable cells
>   have a lock  Uneditable Field.

You can’t edit inline in a list view or on a multi-line view if:

- It contains more than one record type.
- It uses filter logic that contains OR clauses.

You can edit inline in Recently Viewed or Team list views that are predefined to contain only one record type. You can also edit Tasks on the Tasks object home page, even though they’re not in a list view.

Some fields or field types aren’t editable inline.

- Built-in fields like Record ID or Created Date (never editable from
  the user interface)
- Standard fields of type date/time, auto number, roll-up summary,
  record type, master-detail, long text area, Rich Text, checkbox, or
  hierarchy
- Custom date/time fields
- Compound fields including Name, Account Name, address fields, and
  geolocation fields

> NOTE:-  First Name and Last Name are editable.

- The opportunity fields Expected Revenue and Forecast Category
- Custom dependent picklists
- Encrypted text fields

**I am not able to add the Quick Action to this Search Layout, as Owner field is not available in the Quick Action layout.**

> Use the Change Owner page-level button to assign a new owner for up to
>   200 selected **leads, cases, or custom objects**. You can access the
>   button in the page-level action menu in a list view or related list in
>   standard table mode, or in Related List Quick Links.

You can add whatever field you want in list view by configuring search layout.

Note:- You cannot add quick action of type Lightning component or visualforce page to a list view. Other types are supported.

Reference:- [Considerations for Editing Inline in a List View Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews_edit_inline_listview_lex_considerations.htm&type=5)

[Assign a New Owner to Multiple Leads, Cases, or Custom Objects at One Time](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lex_change_owner.htm)

Comment: Hi Sanket:  The last link in your update 'Assign a new owner to multiple leads, cases or custom objects at one time' - this is what I want precisely for a Work Order object.  And I am not able to add the page level 'Change Owner' action.. Is it only supported for Leads, Cases and custom objects?  Not for Work Orders?

Comment: Yes, it will not work for the work order because it is limited to leads cases and custom object